# Swift with Firebase in simple app - lldb error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was following the tutorial on the official Firebase Youtube account (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joVi3thZOqc), but it seemes outdated so I had to read the documentation and apply a couple of changes to get this simple app to work properly. I get lldb error in AppDelegate.swift file:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { //error here

    var window: UIWindow?

    override init(){
        FIRApp.configure()
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

ViewController.swift file:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //FBDataBase variables
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference() //root directory

    //interface variables
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            self.label.text = snapshot.value as? String
        }
    }

    //interface functions
    @IBAction func sunnyPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        ref.child("condition").child("addedByUser").setValue("sunny")
    }

    @IBAction func foggyPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        ref.child("condition").child("addedByUser").setValue("foggy")

    }
}
```

console log:

```
2017-02-05 13:12:40.738 fireDataBaseTest[4745:140438] Firebase automatic screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2017-02-05 13:12:40.848 fireDataBaseTest[4745] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000001] Configuring the default app.
2017-02-05 13:12:40.864 fireDataBaseTest[4745:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3600000 started
2017-02-05 13:12:40.865 fireDataBaseTest[4745:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http://goo.gl/...)
2017-02-05 13:12:40.870: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2017-02-05 13:12:40.913 fireDataBaseTest[4745:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2017-02-05 13:12:41.027 fireDataBaseTest[4745:140438] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<fireDataBaseTest.ViewController 0x7fd09e60e1f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key foggyPressed.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001110cdd4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110b2f21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001110cdc99 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000011063d9df -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 291
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000111d9f293 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
    5   UIKit                               0x000000011201379e -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001110729e0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 256
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000112012122 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1867
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000111da59c5 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 386
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000111da62e7 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000111da661c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 201
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000111da6e70 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000111c704b5 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 71
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000111c70c06 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 293
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000111c84519 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000111bfcf8d -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4818
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000111c030ed -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000111c0026d -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001164a56cb __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001164a5544 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001164a58cd -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111072761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011105798c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111056e76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111056884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000111bfeaea -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    26  UIKit                               0x0000000111c04c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    27  fireDataBaseTest                    0x000000010f40409f main + 111
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000113d8a68d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I'm new to Swift and Firebase so I'm looking forward to get some help. The fix is probably very simple and I'm just missing something because of lack of skill.

Comment: Probably in your storyboard, you don't have correctly set the class.

Comment: You mean that I didn't set a ViewController class to ViewController.swift? I doubt it, it's set by default and the app was running in simulator before applying couple of lines of code including Firebase

Comment: I don't think that the test view controller in the error message was added by default, nor does it have a "foggyPressed" key...

Comment: Ok, thanks. There was one deleted outlet in my Main.storyboard and the issue wasn't connected to the Firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already figured out the error but want to add a few things for guidance.

Your app delegate should look like this (Swift 3, Firebase 3). There are other options as well. This is just a starting point.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FIRApp.configure()
        return true
    }
```

The viewController should be

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
```

and your viewDidLoad method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}
```

Now, your interface functions:

> ```
> @IBAction func sunnyPressed(_ sender: Any) {
>     ref.child("condition").child("addedByUser").setValue("sunny")
> }
> ```

Not sure you going to want to do that as it will write the following node to Firebase

```
rootRef
   condition
     addedByUser: "sunny"
```

you may want something like

```
rootRef
  conditions
    -Yu99sj9jkoe
       addedByUser: "users uid"
       condition: "snowing"
       timestamp: "20170205075600"
       location: "Mountains"
```

The -Yu99sj9jkoe is created with childByAutoId - and the rest is a dictionary written to that child node.

Oh - ensure you have imported your GoogleService-Info.plist file as well which is generated from the Firebase console.

Edit: Follow up to a comment. how do you get the data in a conditions node.

There are a number of ways but for the moment, say we want to get the child data of a specific node. Here's the code

```
let conditionsRef = rootRef.child("conditions")
let thisConditionRef = conditionsRef.child("-Yu99sj9jkoe")
thisConditionRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let conditionDict = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]
    let uid = conditionDict["addedByUser"] as! String
    let location = conditionDict["location"] as! String
    print("uid \(uid) is located in the \(location)"   
})
```

If you want to read all of them in, you would change it to

```
allConditionsRef.observeEvent(.value, with: { snapshot in
```

However, you then need to iterate over the snapshot and address each child. There are numerous posts on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've got two questions: if I'm going to put `ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()` inside the function shouldn't it be inside `viewDidAppear`? It makes more sense to create it when app loads. 2nd question: so it's better to create more self-explanatory description? So to get root/ conditions/ condition I have to create -> `ref.child("conditions").child("condition").setValue("sunny")` so every child is the next level in JSON file?

Comment: Another question - how to get data on the lower level? If I've got root/ conditions/ type and         `ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.label.text = snapshot.value as? String
            print("\(snapshot.value)")
        })` Is it possible to get data from lower level ("conditions" and "type") or I have to create `ref.child("conditions").child("type).observe...`

Comment: ViewDidLoad comes before ViewDidAppear so it will set things up sooner. See [NSViewController)(https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsviewcontroller) in the lifecycle section. Question #2. No. Don't do that. It's best practice to disassociate node names (keys. In this case -Yu99sj9jkoe) from the data they contain so leveraging childByAutoId would allow each user to add a condition, timestamp and location and have them stored separately under the conditions node.

Comment: @codddeer123 I updated the answer to address the final question.

Comment: Hmmm, so snapshot.value is dictionary or an array? Or it doesn't even matter? I've put `if let dict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {` in my code and it works fine.

Comment: @codddeer123 value can be any of the allowed types. In the case, it's a Dictionary. You plan your code to meet your Firebase structure and vice-versa. Please avoid arrays in firebase as they are evil.

Comment: is it ok to put `     ref.child("conditions").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in` and the whole statement which downloads data in viewDidLoad? Because there is small lag when I'm launching the app. Firstly there is a default view from my Main.storyboard and just after a second data appears on the screen

Comment: @codddeer123 Yes. It's very situational though so it depends on your user case and/or the flow of the rest of the app.